# Getting AccessToken from Azure Ad via UserName & Password

Tags: c#, adal

I have a Native Client registered in our Azure AD.

When i'm using

```
var ar = _context.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, returnUri);
```

It opens the Prompt for Username and Password. If I enter them correctly I get a valid AccessToken and everything is fine.

When I'm now trying to enter the credentials in code, via UserCrendtial:

```
var credential = new UserCredential("username", "password");

var ar = _context.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, credential);
```

But both resulting in an Error when I'm trying it with the directly entered Credentials.

> AADSTS65001: No permission to access user information is configured
>   for '4915f024-blah-blah-blah-f580ab5b0487' application, or it is
>   expired or revoked.

I have tried the normal `(string, string)` and the `(string, SecureString)` overload of the UserCredential.
I have tried it with the exact same combination of username & password, which I have entered in the Prompt, of the first overload from AcquireToken.

I have also tried to give the Application in Azure all the Delegated Permissions:

- Read directory data
- Read and write directory data
- Access your organization's directory

And added Windows Azure Service Management API Application with Permission:

- Access Azure Service Management

Nothing helped.

As a sidenote, the Application in the Azure has permissions to a SharePoint O365 Tenant. To Read and Write ListItems I don't know if this is relevant. The Resource i'm passing through is the SharePoint Adress.

I don't need any user access over the Graph Api to the Azure. I only need that AccessToken to access our SharePoint Online.

**Edit:**

**Architecture:**

[image]

**Description:**

We have a Web Api Project which handles the User Authorization, Load Balancing etc. This Web Api Project, will be queried by either Native Dekstop Clients or Hybrid HTML5 & Javascript Mobile Device Apps.

The Web Api Project needs to Read, Create, Update & Delete Data from our SharePoint O365 Tenant. So this where I need the AccessToken to init a ClientContext or send i via a rest response.

Since the Web Api handles the User authorization, there is an endpoint for users to login already and in this endpoint I want to acquire the Token. That's why I want it to be silent, because the "flexbile browser popup" is already there.

Maybe I don't need in this scenario the Token acquiring with Username / Password, but then I don't know how to configure the Azure App right to work with all the different native client's.

Comment: So, you don't need to perform actions on behalf of a user, right? Can you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api? We are using it in our application and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's your case but you can use :

- built in auth (setting 'on' in webapp options; then create express app or/and then chose advanced mode with same apps ids);
- then add AD native client app;
- login to old classic portal there select native app and in config add access to you express/advacsed web app;
- after that you will able login in browser; and with adal lib will able login to access you api from mobile devices;

for more see ms docs and samples;

Answer (score -2):

The direct use of username and password has important limitations, please make sure you are not stumbling on any of the ones listed in http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/.
Also note, nothing that requires displaying a user consent screen (as all the permissions you described will) or specific disambiguation steps (like trying to use a guest user from X to access a resource protected by tenant Y) will work.
What is your scenario? Any specific reason for which you want to use username/password instead of the more flexible browser popup?